# python subprocess not outputting all lines

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, tcpdump

I am using python to run tcpdump to capture some probe requests from my phone.
Right now, I am just printing it to the console.

```
def dumpNexus(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "tcpdump", "-i", "mon.wlan0", "-e", "-s", "0", "type", "mgt", "subtype", "probe-req", "and", "ether host", "bc:f5:ac:f2:xx:xx"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
            print proc.stdout.readline()
```

My problem is that when I run this program, it won't print all of the lines that are being written by `tcpdump`.
If I run the `tcpdump` command and compare its output the the python program, the python program has significantly fewer packets displayed.

`tcpdump` will state that it captured 28 packets but only 11 are outputted through the subprocess `stdout`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

thanks

Comment: Well you're calling `readline()` twice, what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you're calling `readline()` twice. First time inside of `iter` and then inside of the loop and so you end up ignoring the line returned by `iter`. A fix will be:

```
for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line
```

Or you can simply do:

```
for line in proc.stdout:
    print line
```

Comment: Ok yep, that was definitely an issue. Thank you

Comment: @user2413192: to avoid doubling all newlines, add comma at the end of the print statement (`sys.stdout.softspace` hack): `print line,` (<-- comma). `for line in proc.stdout` would delay output due to [hidden read-ahead bug on Python 2](http://bugs.python.org/issue3907), use `iter(proc.stdout.readline, b'')` instead. See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that for something like this you want tcpdump to be in the "line buffered mode" - use the `-l` flag.